# How to disable ribbon button based on Form in Dynamics CRM 2016?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, ribbon-button

In this case I have two forms (Information & Manager) with ribbon Approve TOP. This button only enabled/view in Manager form.

I have followed this [tutorial](http://missdynamicscrm.blogspot.co.id/2015/02/show-hide-ribbon-based-on-specific-form-in-multiple-forms-crm.html). I have already added javascript snippet that I set to my ribbon button enable rules. This is a sample of my code:

```
function EnableDisableRibbon_ApproveTop() {
    try {
        var formLabel;
        var currForm = Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.getCurrentItem();
        formLabel = currForm.getLabel();
        
        if (formLabel == "Manager") {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert("EnableDisableRibbon_ApproveTop : " + e.message);
    }
}
```

When I opened that form I got this error:

> EnableDisableRibbon_ApproveTop : Cannot read property 'getCurrentItem' of null
>
> EnableDisableRibbon_ApproveTop : Cannot read property 'getLabel' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You have to add null check before trying to access child properties/methods like below:

```
function EnableDisableRibbon_ApproveTop() {
    try {
        var formLabel;
        var selector = Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector;   

        if(selector != null){
            var currForm = selector.getCurrentItem();

            if(currForm != null){
                formLabel = currForm.getLabel();

                if (formLabel == "Manager") {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert("EnableDisableRibbon_ApproveTop : " + e.message);
    }
}
```

2.Make sure the user have access to both forms through security role, otherwise `Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector` returns null for single default form. [read more](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/df1f3680-13e8-4a80-ae33-aec16dc89497/crm-2011-get-form-name-using-javascript?forum=crmdevelopment)

3.Check the turbo form settings for legacy rendering, if it helps you to solve this error

4.If the control is delayed loading - try `setTimeout` method to retry the snippet to call the `EnableDisableRibbon_ApproveTop()` method one more time

Update:
The [blogpost](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/aaronbellscrmblog/archive/2016/07/11/how-to-disable-a-crm-2016-ribbon-button-based-on-form-name) you mentioned is another workaround, by setting the global `formName` variable from each form script instead of `formSelector`. This is done by overloaded `set_formname()` function inside Enablerule function `RibbonButtonEnable`.

Comment: why am i still get null value? perhaps there is some issue in dinamic crm 2016? i tried in dinamic crm 365 and it work perfectly

Comment: @aminvincent did you try debugging?

Comment: yes i have tried it.. my ribbon button still appear

Comment: the problem is ribbon **Cannot read property 'getCurrentItem' of null**. but when i tried call js from form onload it work

Comment: @aminvincent that’s right, by point 4 retry after a second using setTimeout & see if it’s not null..

Comment: i don't try to doing for 4 step. buat i try to following this tutorial : https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/aaronbellscrmblog/archive/2016/07/11/how-to-disable-a-crm-2016-ribbon-button-based-on-form-name but it doesn't work becase the tutorail unclear.